# Is there a way to check whether a field contains any element from an array using $ne? (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to be able to query a field that does not contain any of the elements in an array.

for example, I have an array of objects (venue)  :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $match: { roomNo: {$ne:venue}}},

                    ])
```

how shall I access the array in the object and query using $ne?

Is there a way to do this?
I was not able to achieve what I wanted using the above method.

Comment: Your code seems valid. Is "venue" a variable ? If not, try to add single quotes around that value.

Comment: venue is an array actually.

Comment: Then try to use $nin instead of $ne

Comment: I tried, i got an error saying that $nin needs an array. Is this because I have objects inside my array?

Comment: Can you share one complete Document of Collection?
is roomNo a array like : roomNo : [{ _id: 'E0-1-10' }, { _id: 'E0-1-09' } ]?

Answer (score 0):

Use **$nin** in the query 
For Eg: **db.collection.find( { roomNo: { $nin: [ 5, 15 ] } } )**

Comment: I have an array of objects (json). Is there a way to do that with jsons?

Comment: Please share the sample DB Object and the list of Object which  you want  match

Comment: ```[{ _id: 'E0-1-10' },
 { _id: 'E0-1-09' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This example works:

```
db.collection.save({ roomNo : 1, floor : 1})
db.collection.save({ roomNo : 2, floor : 1})
db.collection.save({ roomNo : 3, floor : 1})

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {venue: [2,3]}
    },
    {
        $match: { roomNo: {$nin : venue}}
    }
])
```

try it